# Why does Minecraft grass have different colors, and how can I make it bright colored?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

[image: Minecraft grass showcasing 'brown' grass]

As you can see the left and right parts are bright but the middle part is pale. Why is it like that?

And how can I fix it? (Make it all bright green)

Comment: Wow that would be so cool if we could re-color the grass somehow. Too bad we can.t

Comment: @Ender We can! It's just a texture in the default resource pack.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie that's good to know actually, but I was looking more at the possibility of some in game dye item to seriously get cool with it. Suppose we could just use wool though.

Comment: I kinda wish grass & leaves texture would also change based on its proximity to a water source - kinda like farmland. It's no fun creating an 'oasis' in the desert if they all end up looking brown...

Comment: @Robotnik Hm! That's the kind of mod that I would make, and I think I know how I'd approach it (basically like farmland hydration). It's been so long since I've modded though that I'm not likely to tackle it soon. :(

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Grass is different colours in different biomes, and you're seeing the "dry desert" grass colour in the middle of your screenshot. The difference in colours is controlled by one texture file though, so it's easy enough to fix by installing a resource/texture pack that changes that file to be one uniform green instead of a gradient of greens and yellows.

Texture packs like that used to be popular due to nostalgia for the grass in older versions of Minecraft, but my googling just now reveals that they're a harder to find now. Since googling turned up nothing except broken links, I threw one together:

### [Green Grass Texture Pack](http://eggdropsoap.pipemaze.com/minecraft/resourcepacks/greengrass/Green%20Grass.zip)

[image: A left-right split image showing the before and after effect of the Green Grass texture pack on the appearance of a Savanna biome]

If you want a different green than the one I picked and have some facility with zip-file creation and image editing software, you can find the one texture file it contains and change the triangle of green to a green more to your liking.

#### Installing a Texture Pack

1. Open Minecraft
2. Click <kbd>Options…</kbd> then <kbd>Resource Packs…</kbd>
3. Click <kbd>Open resource pack folder</kbd>
4. Switch away from Minecraft to your desktop (if it didn't automatically)
5. Copy the downloaded file in to the **resourcepacks** folder that Minecraft just opened
6. Switch back to Minecraft
7. The new resource pack won't show up until you close the Resource Packs screen and reopen it: click <kbd>Done</kbd> then click <kbd>Resource Packs…</kbd> to open it again
8. Select the new resource pack and click <kbd>Done</kbd>

Comment: There is a similar issue with leaves IIRC

Comment: @ratchetfreak Yes. You can see in the screenshot that I left the trees alone, as the question didn't ask how to change trees. It's an equally-easy fix though.

Comment: Do you have this for the leaves and other plants too?

Answer (score 9):

Grass color is based on biome. The grass in the middle is in a desert biome. You can't really control this without just picking another spot (I guess if you really wanted to you could change the biome with MCEdit).

Jungle biomes have the brightest green grass, forest and plains biomes also have fairly green grass. Pretty much any biome except the particularly arid ones will have grass like the grass surrounding the brown grass in your screenshot (with the exception of swamp biomes, which features really dark green grass).

Answer (score 0):

Basically, if you don't like the color of the grass, go find a biome where there is grass shade you like. The jungle has the brightest shade, if my memory does not deceive me. That's the best help I can offer. If you don't want to deal with all the jungle trees, a plains biome is a nice shade too.